# An associated query is returning a partial record for a particular user

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth, associated, missing-data

[This query](http://stackauth.com/users/3e09f16e-999c-4b38-b729-4d3c22d14106/associated) returns (in addition to several complete records) this incomplete one:

```
{
  "user_id": 2196,
  "user_type": "registered",
  "display_name": "Wil",
  "reputation": 151,
  "email_hash": "8e40b955ba72299d98374726cdc1573d"
}
```

As you can see, several fields are missing, not the least of which is the `on_site` structure.

This is apparently this user's Area 51 account (I didn't know the API returned any Area 51 data).

This has been occurring since sometime after Fri Nov 12 21:13:00 UTC 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, there were recently some association changes on the main sites and this is a consequence of that.

The API is not meant to return association information for Area51 (and Area51 doesn't expose an API itself).  This has been fixed; such data is no longer returned.