# An associated query is returning a partial record for Area 51

Tags: bug, stackauth, associated, area51, missing-data

[This issue](https://stackapps.com/questions/1782/an-associated-query-is-returning-a-partial-record-for-a-particular-user) has recurred (and is ongoing) as of a couple of weeks ago.

Most notably, as before, the `on_site` attribute is missing from Area 51.

This is API 1.0, by the way.

Comment: Could you please add a sample query so we can try to reproduce this?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Sorry, the previous question I linked to in this question has a link to a suitable query in it, reproduced [here](http://stackauth.com/users/3e09f16e-999c-4b38-b729-4d3c22d14106/associated). Search for '"user_id": 2196' in the result to see the pertinent record.

Comment: Fixed as of April 2.